# Run PS1 script as admin

Tags: powershell

I need a PS1 script that will ask for domain admin credentials and then run elevated all in 1 window without using a shortcut.

This is as close as I have been able to get:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs Get-Credential "Domain\admin.account"
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity "account"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

The current problem is that it opens another window.  I need it to prompt for domain admin creds and then elevate the window it's in OR bring the script into the new admin window.

The objective here is to allow certain system admins to unlock there test/non-elevated accounts by running this script with their limited-admin accounts without having to go into AD or bug me BUT still require them to enter their proper limited-admin password.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why *domain* admin operations need local elevation? Usually you can specify network credentials for each operation, as being a local admin has no relevance to modifying an AD object.

Comment: @user1686 - The only reason a PowerShell script would need to be elevate is if it ran a Cmdlet that normally required elevation.  A process ran by an user with elevated permissions will by default run with the lowest permissions possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is how not to open a new window, you may use this parameter
of
[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2):

> **-NoNewWindow**
>
> Start the new process in the current console window. By default on
> Windows, PowerShell opens a new window. On non-Windows systems, you
> never get a new window.